# How to unroot my TF101

Tags: asus-eee-pad-transformer, unrooting

The backlight on my Asus Transformer broke and i need to send it in for repair. I bought the tablet used already rooted. I have no idea which root it is, and I can't see anything on the screen. I tried unrooting using the [method provided here](http://www.tabletroms.com/forums/transformer-rom-development/1071-asus-transformer-nvflash-stock-3-1-stock-3-2-recovery-roms-unbricking-tools-6.html), but it didn't detect my device. Also it won't go into APX mode and I can't see anything that's happening on the screen. I was thinking I could connect the tablet to a TV, but I don't want to purchase an HDMI cable before I have a sure method that will unroot my tablet. The serial starts with B6O, and since it's the backlight that's broken I can still see very limited parts of the screen.

Comment: Did the warranty transfer from whoever you bought it from?  Otherwise root shouldn't matter.

Comment: The waranty did transfer, i already called asus and got all the information to send it in. Although i still need to unroot it. Please help